# How can I use my APC UPS with Ubuntu?

Tags: ups

I have a [APC 350](http://www.apc.com/products/family/index.cfm?id=270&tab=models), and I'd like to use it with Ubuntu 11.10.

Functionality I'd like:

- Show in the GNOME battery indicator how much time is left on the UPS, like this:

[image]

- Have options for how longer after it goes on battery power until it shuts down.

[image]

*(Images [via here](http://www.davidalison.com/2008/06/finding-and-setting-up-ups-for-mac.html), and [here](http://www.macdrifter.com/2011/06/the-power-of-backup-hardware/))*

Is this possible, and if so, what software do I need to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the usb cable that comes with your ups and simply connecting it to the usb port the battery icon shows up.

Comment: Odd, I never noticed that. what about configuration of it?

Comment: haven't seen any type of config it only gives statistics and time to full time to empty a lot of ups info.